# How to make the content scroll in a webview?

Tags: android, html, iframe, scroll, android-webview

Have an html which has some content seems cannot be scrollable after loaded into android webview.

The same html if directly tested with browser it seems scrolling fine.  Does anyone have same issue?

==============

**Update:**
For the scrolling issue, it turns out that in the code there is a listener disabled the the MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE.

```
val listener = object : OnTouchListener {
        override fun onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            return event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
        }
    }

    webview.setOnTouchListener(listener)
```

*Now only issue is why the iframe does not display the content?*

---

There are two html files,  `test-scroll.html`  and `test-scroll-content.html (has a table as content)`

test-scroll.html:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .test_container_div {
                position: relative;
                width: 360px;
                height: 80px;
                overflow: scroll;
            }


        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p> table in this page</p>

    <div class="test_container_div">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Eve</td>
                <td>Jackson</td>
                <td>94</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>80</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>zbr</td>
                <td>Ford</td>
                <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Elis</td>
                <td>Liu</td>
                <td>94</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Pter</td>
                <td>Hans</td>
                <td>80</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <p> table in iframe srcdoc</p>
    <div class="test_container_div">
        <iframe scrolling="no"
                srcdoc="<table>
            <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Eve</td>
                <td>Jackson</td>
                <td>94</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>80</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>zbr</td>
                <td>Ford</td>
                <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Elis</td>
                <td>Liu</td>
                <td>94</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Pter</td>
                <td>Hans</td>
                <td>80</td>
            </tr>
        </table>">

        </iframe>
    </div>

    <p> table in iframe src</p>
    <div class="test_container_div">

        <iframe width="100% !important" height="300px"
                src="test-scroll-content.html"
                frameborder="1" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

    </div>

    <p>image in div </p>
    <div class="test_container_div">
        <img width="100% !important"
             src="img_2.jpg">
        </img>
    </div>

    <p>image in iframe </p>
    <div class="test_container_div">
        <iframe width="100% !important" height="200px"
                src="img_2.jpg"
                frameborder="1"  scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="">
        </iframe>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

which tested a couple cases:

1. a table in a div, div has `height: 80px` and `overflow: scroll`
2. the same table put in iframe as its `srcdoc`
3. in an iframe load in the conetnt `src="test-scroll-content.html"`
4. an `<img>` has src points to a local image
5. the same image file but load into a iframe's src

when directly loads the test-scroll.html into browser `file:///Users/linma9/Documents/test-scroll.html`, seems all cases in browser the content can scroll.

(it is easier to see the scroll after loaded in the browser then do "inspect" with chrome develop tool).

[image]

With android project and put the same files under the asset folder.

and do either

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test-scroll.html")
```

or put the test-scroll.html content as string inside a function `fun getTestScrollHtmlStr() : String{}` and
do:

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",
                getTestScrollHtmlStr(),
                "text/html", "utf-8",null)
```

when run on android device,  seems both way they can not scroll the content

(and another issue it cannot shows the content loaded with `iframe src=` ???)

[image]

Does anyone know how to make the content scrollable when loading the them into android webview (either in iframe or not)?

test-scroll-content.html:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p> directly put in div</p>

    <div>
        <table >
            <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Eve</td>
                <td>Jackson</td>
                <td>94</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>80</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>zbr</td>
                <td>Ford</td>
                <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Elis</td>
                <td>Liu</td>
                <td>94</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Pter</td>
                <td>Hans</td>
                <td>80</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Did you added scrollview in your xml?

Comment: no, the webview is in a relativeLayout. does the webview need to be in side scrollview in order to work?